Understanding the measurement of "evil" using the GHZ effect
I was reading this interesting article originally published by Quanta Magazine, which tries to explain the GHZ effect in simple terms.

The GHZ effect is, in the physicist Sidney Coleman’s words, “quantum
mechanics in your face.” ... Once internalized, the message of
the GHZ effect is unforgettable and mind-expanding.

I want that mind-expanding experience, but unfortunately, I find the article a bit confusing, perhaps because what they call "measurements of evil" does not appear to be clearly defined. Let me quickly summarise my understanding and perhaps someone can clarify what I am misinterpreting:
The system analysed in the article defines entangled pairs as having two complementary measurable properties, shape, and colour. Each property has two measurable states, square (s) or circular (c) for shape or red (R) or blue (B) for colour.
For quantum entangled objects with complementary properties, the possible results are restricted to:
$\begin{matrix}
(BB) & (cB) & (sB) \\
(RR) & (cR) & (sR) \\
(Bc) & (Rc) & (cc) \\
(Bs) & (Rs) & (ss) \\
\end{matrix}$
because for these entangled objects, if both observers measure the same property at the same time, they must both get the same result, so combinations (R,B), (B,R), (c,s), and (s,c) are not allowed. I think I get that part.
They then introduce the GHZ experimental setup where the states of 3 entangled particles are measured by 3 independent observers.

Each experimenter, separately, finds maximally random results. When
she measures a q-on’s shape, she is equally likely to find a square or
a circle; when she measures its color, red or blue are equally likely.
So far, so mundane.

Now this is where it gets confusing to me: They also introduce a classification of the correlation results that are defined as either good or evil, where circular shapes and blue colors are classified as “evil”.

when all three chose to measure color, they found that exactly 1 or 3
measurements were evil

What red behave differently to blue?
Next, two of the observers measure shape and one measures colour. When they do this, they only get a {measure of evil} equal to {2} or {0}, so if the first two particles are both measured to be the same shape the remaining particle can only be red and if the shapes are different the remaining colour must be blue. Again, why does red behave differently to blue?
What am I missing or misinterpreting? Is it something to do with the way the GHZ experiment is arranged, so that the observers are forced to make the measurements in a particular order?
EDIT: So far no one has really addressed "why does red behave differently to blue" in the answers. Since posting this question, I have done a little more research and I think I can explain that aspect of the question. Referring to this paper on a real GHZ experiment, it becomes clear they start with 4 particles, but one of the particles is removed from the game, (e.g. blue). Since blue has been detected, the remaining partner of that particle is now known to be blue. We are now left with 3 particles and one is guaranteed to be blue. This leaves one pair of entangled particles and they are either both red or both blue, so any permutation must have either 3 blues or 1 blue and 2 reds. This is why red appears to be special. If it was a red particle that was removed, then blue would appear to be special.

I don't think you've misunderstood anything. The special thing about the GHZ setup is that it is possible to create a state that has the properties you describe. The fact that this is possible is what is weird. With some more math you could dig in and see precisely how this state is defined, but that won't "explain" anything per se, just let you see under the hood to see why the rules of quantum mechanics allow this state to be created. In terms of "what is special about red" -- it is just how the state was set up, you could also arrange a state with red/blue reversed.

Can someone clarify what shape and colour represent? For example, if shape is linear polarisation (Square = vertical, Circle = horizontal), then would colour be represented by some other observable e.g. circular polarisation (red = clockwise, blue = anticlockwise) ?

You could represent the abstract description in the article by the spin of an electron, with spin along the $z$ axis representing shape (spin up along $z$ being circle and spin down being square), and spin along the $x$ axis representing color (spin up along the $x$ axis being red and spin down being blue).

The article says:

Let us call square shapes and red colors “good,” and circular shapes and blue colors “evil.” The experimenters discover that whenever two of them chose to measure shape but the third measured color, they found that exactly 0 or 2 results were “evil” (that is, circular or blue). But when all three chose to measure color, they found that exactly 1 or 3 measurements were evil.

I don't find those attribute choices very elucidating. Let's go with this instead: you and two friends are trying to cooperate to win a game. In this game, you're allowed to meet to agree on a strategy, then you're separated so you can't communicate, and each of you is asked one of two questions, say X and Y, and must give one of two answers, say yes and no. The winning conditions are: if one of you is asked X and the other two Y, you must give an even number of yes answers, while if all three of you are asked X then you must give an odd number of yes answers. Otherwise it doesn't matter what you answer, and let's say the other cases don't happen.
You can win 50% of the time by answering randomly. Is there any way to win 100% of the time? Here's an argument that there isn't. First, there can't be any randomness or individual free choice in a guaranteed winning strategy because then there would be a nonzero chance of someone answering either yes or no while the other two's answers stay the same, and one of those answers would have the wrong parity. So you have to agree on every answer in advance. Count up the number of agreed-upon yes answers to the XYY, YXY, and YYX cases (nine answers in total). The sum is even because the sum for each individual case has to be even. Each answer to a Y question appears twice in the sum, so if you remove them from the sum the total is still even. So you will give an even number of yes answers in the XXX case, which violates the rules. So you can't win.
But actually you can win, if you create a certain entangled state of three electrons during the strategy phase, each take one electron, and measure its spin along the X or Y axis depending on which question you're asked. So something is wrong with the argument in the last paragraph. What's wrong with it?
This is very similar to Bell's argument, which can be phrased as a similar game. The main difference is that in the GHZ game the quantum strategy always wins, while in the Bell game it just wins more often than the best classical strategy. But the GHZ experiment is still probabilistic, because a classical strategy can win some of the time (e.g. by random guessing) so you have to do many trials to rule that out.

You haven't misunderstood anything, it is just that quantum mechanics is weird.
We can dig into the math a little bit to see how a proper mathematical description of the GHZ state maps onto the colorful analogy in the Quanta article. I am following wikipedia, which seems to lead to a different set of possible outcomes than what is described in the Quanta article, but is the same principle (and does lead to the same weirdness in terms of some possibilities you would expect classically being missing).
First, just some rules in case you aren't familiar with quantum mechanics. In quantum mechanics, a system is described by a state $|\Psi\rangle$. We can express $\Psi$ as a superposition (or sum) over different possible measurement outcomes. When we do this, the absolute value of the square of the coefficient of a given outcome, is the probability that we will measure that outcome.
In our experiment, we will have three electrons, and will measure the spin of the electron along different axes. Given an axis of rotation, whenever we measure the electron's spin along this axis we always find that it is either $+\hbar/2$ or $-\hbar/2$, we typically call these possibilities "spin up" or "spin down" along that axis.
We can represent the possibility that "particle 1 has spin up along the $z$ axis" as $|\uparrow\rangle_{1,z}$. Similarly, "particle 2 has spin down along the $x$ axis would be $|\leftarrow\rangle_{2,x}$. Then in this notation, a state where "particle 1 has spin up along z, particle 2 has spin up along $z$, particle 3 has spin down along $x$" would look like
$$
|\uparrow\rangle_{1,z}|\uparrow\rangle_{2,z}|\leftarrow\rangle_{3,x}
$$
The GHZ state is a special state that has the form
$$
|\Psi_\rm{GHZ}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Big(|\downarrow\rangle_{1,z}|\downarrow\rangle_{2,z}|\downarrow\rangle_{3,z} + |\uparrow\rangle_{1,z}|\uparrow\rangle_{2,z}|\uparrow\rangle_{3,z} \Big)
$$
This means there is a 50% probability of finding the particles all spin up along z, or all spin down along z. There is zero probability of finding, say, 2 particles with spin up along z and 1 particle with spin down along z.
Now, there is a rule, which I cannot justify in this answer, but which follows from properties of rotations in quantum mechanics, that allows us to relate a spin up state along z to a superposition of spin up and down states along x (and similarly for spin down)
\begin{eqnarray}
|\downarrow\rangle_{z} &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big(|\rightarrow\rangle_{x} + |\leftarrow\rangle_{x}\Big) \\
%
|\uparrow\rangle_{z} &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big(|\rightarrow\rangle_{x} - |\leftarrow\rangle_{x}\Big)
\end{eqnarray}
Given these rules, and doing some algebra, we can rewrite the GHZ state as
\begin{eqnarray}
|\Psi_\rm{GHZ}\rangle &=& \frac{1}{2} \Big(|\downarrow\rangle_{1,z}|\downarrow\rangle_{2,z} +|\uparrow\rangle_{1,z}|\uparrow\rangle_{2,z}\Big) |\rightarrow\rangle_{3, x} \\
&& + \frac{1}{2} \Big(|\downarrow\rangle_{1,z}|\downarrow\rangle_{2,z} -|\uparrow\rangle_{1,z}|\uparrow\rangle_{2,z}\Big) |\leftarrow\rangle_{3, x}
\end{eqnarray}
So the possible measurement outcomes (all with probability $1/4$, since that is the square of the coefficient $\pm 1/2$) are:

Particle 1 spin down along z, Particle 2 spin down along z, Particle 3 spin up along x
Particle 1 spin up along z, Particle 2 spin up along z, Particle 3 spin up along x
Particle 1 spin down along z, Particle 2 spin down along z, Particle 3 spin down along x
Particle 1 spin up along z, Particle 2 spin up along z, Particle 3 spin down along x

Note that there are naively 8 possibilities (if we measure particles 1 and 2 along z and particle 3 along x) -- we never see combinations outcomes like "Particle 1 spin up along z, Particle 2 spin down along z, Particle 3 spin down along x".
Now, if you replace:

"spin along z" with "color"

"spin up along z" with "red"
"spin down along z" with blue"


"spin along x" with "shape"

"spin up along x" with "circle"
"spin down along x" with square"



and stare at the above possibilities, the state I've described matches onto the combinations that RRc, RRs, BBc, BBs are allowed, but something like RBc is never observed. This isn't the exact same setup that your article describes, but it leads to a similar conclusion that there are combinations which you would expect to occur if the measurements of the qubits were classical and independent, but which don't occur in quantum mechanics. (And you'd expect the qubits not to be able to interact after they are measured since after entangling them we can separate them by arbitrarily large distances, say to different galaxies). I suspect the difference between what I'm describing and your article boils down to a different way of mapping "red, blue" and "circle, square" to spin states, but I'd have to look more closely.
